# Test automation of authorization prompt - chrome

Tags: authentication, automation, authorization, cypress

I am trying to automate a simple login within this alert prompt authorization using cypress and javascript
I came across different solutions but I cant find the proper one.

What I actually do is I visit website with :

cy.visit('https://xxx/',{failOnStatusCode: false}) // Internal website with the fafailOnStatusCode: false

If I do not use failOnStatusCode: false I cant get to the prompt and I get an cypress message about using failOnStatusCode: false

But I am stuck after this step and neither cy.visit('https://username:password@xxx/',{failOnStatusCode: false})
 is not working ...

Thanks for any comments and help. This is my first thread here :)
[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPaev.png)

Comment: At the moment I figure out a bit from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoYkjId6iVA&t=4s but I cant pass more than 2 things into the prompt with this code:

cy.window().then(function($win){
  
  cy.stub($win, 'prompt').returns(???)

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
it('login prompt xxx', function () {
  cy.setCookie("name", "value");
  cy.visit("yourUrl.com", {
    headers: {
       authorization: 'Basic token'
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
```

Test automated in cypress.

Open up the developer tools in chrome to find out these 2 things.
1.You have to know your cookie name and value from console. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie.html
2.Also you have to know your authorization which can be found in console.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html